# Evaluating a Nested For Loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I am trying to evaluate how this nested For loop works. Can someone explain to me how the values for i and j increase and behave with each iteration with respect to x and y inputs? Using x = 3 and y = 5, how does it compile?

```
x,y = map(int,input("Insert two digits to generate a 2-dimensional array: ").split(',')) # applies int to both numbers
lst = [[i*j for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]  
print(lst)
```

The question can be found [here](https://github.com/darkprinx/100-plus-Python-programming-exercises-extended/blob/master/Status/Day%202.md). Note that this question is not homework but my own independent learning.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to see the process is to modify your code

```
lst = [[f'i is {i}, j is {j}' for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]
```

And then print the list to see the iterations.

For x=3, y=5, the above will print

```
[['i is 0, j is 0', 'i is 0, j is 1', 'i is 0, j is 2', 'i is 0, j is 3', 'i is 0, j is 4'], 
['i is 1, j is 0', 'i is 1, j is 1', 'i is 1, j is 2', 'i is 1, j is 3', 'i is 1, j is 4'], 
['i is 2, j is 0', 'i is 2, j is 1', 'i is 2, j is 2', 'i is 2, j is 3', 'i is 2, j is 4']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [[i*j for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]
```

with `x=3` and `y=5` can be rewritten as:

```
>>> res = []
>>> for i in range(3):
...     l = []
...     for j in range(5):
...             l.append(i*j)
...     res.append(l)
... 
>>> res
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

So, in practice you create 3 lists and each list contains 5 elements given by product of i and j.

Comment: when i attempted this question, this was my way of thinking. The solution was interesting because it was completed in one line. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is call list comprehension. A very helpfull coding method python provides us. It works exactly the same way the anyother nested loop does. Maybe this part of code can lead you to better understanding.

lst = [[i*j for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]

```
x,y = 3,5
list1 = []
list2 = []
for j in range(y):
    for i in range(x):
        list1.append(i*j)
    list2.append(list1)
    list1 = []

print(list2)
```

This code does exactly the same at your's code will do with x=3, y = 5.

OUTPUT:

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 6], [0, 4, 8]]